# Detecting word between specific words with PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

for example,

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="content" id="editor"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="alltext">
<form>
```

Then I type: Humans have ==brain== and it helps them learn things.
After that, I want this thing to find the word between == and ==.

```
$all_text = $_POST["alltext"];
if (a word is between '==' and '==') { 
    $special_word = the word between '==' and '==';
} else {
    do nothing 
}
```

and the output I desire is the variable `$special_word` is set to `brain`.

It is more like [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) where words between # and # is **heading 1** and words between ## and ## is **heading 2**.

**Please** help me solve this *puzzle*.

Comment: https://eval.in/898683

Comment: Read about [`preg_match()`](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: @splash58 what is the [1] for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `preg_match` to get the sub-string:

```
$str = 'Humans have ==brain== and it helps them learn things';
preg_match('/==(.*?)==/', $str, $match);
$special_word = $match[1];
```

Comment: @sjsam No, `$_REQUEST['content']`. Oh wait, the OP has got that wrong too.

Comment: @MrLister : Right indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regex to match the string, then you can simply extract it and put it into a variable.

Here is the regex:

```
/\w+/
```

You can use PHP regex function to match or extract from strings.

Here is the reference to PHP regex functions:

[PHP PCRE functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)

P.S: `preg_match()` should do well here in your scenario.

P.S: If you are trying to extract the word brain form a sentence you should use regex like this:

```
/==(.*?)==/
```